# Transform Binary to XML in OutSequence from WCF Service Proxy in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wcf, wso2, xelement, wso2-esb

I'm using a proxy service in WSO2 ESB in between a REST api and a WCF Service. The WCF service that I am calling accepts and returns an XElement object. When the response of the WCF service enters the out sequence of the proxy the result is in binary.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <axis2ns43:binary xmlns:axis2ns43="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"></axis2ns43:binary>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The message in the soap body should look something like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <Location><Result>Success</Result></Location>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I transform the binary message into the actual XML that it is supposed to be? I'm guessing I need to use either a formatted or builder mediator to accomplish this, I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

ESB 4..6.0, by default it uses passthru transport, which doesn't build message..
But with your binary out put, i can confirm taht ESB didnt receve any message..(ie: teh 'success' msg)
If it received,
you could see, something following like that;

```
  <axis2ns43:binary xmlns:axis2ns43="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvY</axis2ns43:binary>
```

Can you switch back to NIO transport(you need to enable the transport sender and receiver at axi2.xml) and see, what you are actually receiving?